# Brute force stable marriage, How to implements all possible pairs between 2 lists?

Tags: python, stable-marriage

I'm trying to implement an algorithm to find all stable marriage solutions  with a brute force approach without the Gale-Shapley algorithm (because it gives us only 2 of them).
I'm using the checking mechanism found in [rosettacoode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem#Python) but I'm having an hard time trying to find a way to create all possible matches with no repetitions (the kind you have with 2 for cycles)
e.g

```
 from these 2 lists [a,b,c] and [d,e,f] create
 [(a,d),(b,e),(c,f)]
 [(a,d),(b,f),(c,e)]
 [(a,e),(b,f),(c,d)]
 [(a,e),(b,d),(c,f)]
 [(a,f),(b,d),(c,e)]
 [(a,f),(b,e),(c,d)]
```

**UPDATE1:**
With all the solutions so far I'm not able to run it when it gets big.
I should probably do it recursively without storing long data structures, testing the single result when I get it and discard the others . I came out with this solution but still has problems because gives me some repetition and something that is missing. I don't know how to fix it, and sorry my brain is melting!

```
boys=['a','b','c']
girls=['d','e','f']

def matches(boys, girls, dic={}):    
    if len(dic)==3:     #len(girls)==0 geves me more problems
            print dic       #just for testing with few elements
            #run the stability check
        else:
            for b in boys:
                for g in girls:
                    dic[b]=g
                    bb=boys[:]
                    bb.remove(b)
                    gg=girls[:]
                    gg.remove(g)
                    matches(bb,gg, dic)
        dic.clear()
matches(boys,girls)
```

gives me this output

```
{'a': 'd', 'c': 'f', 'b': 'e'}   <-
{'a': 'e', 'c': 'f', 'b': 'd'}       <-
{'a': 'f', 'c': 'e', 'b': 'd'}
{'a': 'e', 'c': 'f', 'b': 'd'}       <-
{'a': 'd', 'c': 'f', 'b': 'e'}   <-
{'a': 'd', 'c': 'e', 'b': 'f'}           <-
{'a': 'e', 'c': 'd', 'b': 'f'}
{'a': 'd', 'c': 'e', 'b': 'f'}           <-
{'a': 'd', 'c': 'f', 'b': 'e'}   <-
```

**UPDATE 2**
My complete working exercise inspired by @Zags (inspired by @Jonas):

```
guyprefers = {
 'A':   ['P','S','L','M','R','T','O','N'],
 'B':   ['M','N','S','P','O','L','T','R'],
 'D':   ['T','P','L','O','R','M','N','S'],
 'E':   ['N','M','S','O','L','R','T','P'],
 'F':   ['S','M','P','L','N','R','T','O'],
 'G':   ['L','R','S','P','T','O','M','N'],
 'J':   ['M','P','S','R','N','O','T','L'],
 'K':   ['N','T','O','P','S','M','R','L']
 }
galprefers = {
    'L': ['F','D','J','G','A','B','K','E'],
    'M': ['K','G','D','F','J','B','A','E'],
    'N': ['A','F','G','B','E','K','J','D'],
    'O': ['K','J','D','B','E','A','F','G'],
    'P': ['G','E','J','D','K','A','B','F'],
    'R': ['B','K','F','D','E','G','J','A'],
    'S': ['J','F','B','A','K','G','E','D'],
    'T': ['J','E','A','F','B','D','G','K']
}

guys = sorted(guyprefers.keys())
gals = sorted(galprefers.keys())

def permutations(iterable):      #from itertools a bit simplified
    pool = tuple(iterable)       #just to understand what it is doing
    n = len(pool)
    indices = range(n)
    cycles = range(n, 0, -1)
    while n:
        for i in reversed(range(n)):
            cycles[i] -= 1
            if cycles[i] == 0:
                indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
                cycles[i] = n - i
            else:
                j = cycles[i]
                indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
                yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:n])
                break
        else:
            return

def check(engaged):           #thanks to rosettacode
    inversengaged = dict((v,k) for k,v in engaged.items())
    for she, he in engaged.items():
        shelikes = galprefers[she]
        shelikesbetter = shelikes[:shelikes.index(he)]
        helikes = guyprefers[he]
        helikesbetter = helikes[:helikes.index(she)]
        for guy in shelikesbetter:
            guysgirl = inversengaged[guy]
            guylikes = guyprefers[guy]
            if guylikes.index(guysgirl) > guylikes.index(she):
                return False
        for gal in helikesbetter:
            girlsguy = engaged[gal]
            gallikes = galprefers[gal]
            if gallikes.index(girlsguy) > gallikes.index(he):
                return False
    return True

match_to_check={}
for i in permutations(guys):
    couples = sorted(zip(i, gals))
    for couple in couples:
        match_to_check[couple[1]]=couple[0]
    if check(match_to_check):
        print match_to_check
    match_to_check.clear()
```

with the correct output:

```
{'M': 'F', 'L': 'D', 'O': 'K', 'N': 'A', 'P': 'G', 'S': 'J', 'R': 'B', 'T': 'E'}
{'M': 'F', 'L': 'D', 'O': 'K', 'N': 'B', 'P': 'G', 'S': 'J', 'R': 'E', 'T': 'A'}
{'M': 'J', 'L': 'D', 'O': 'K', 'N': 'A', 'P': 'G', 'S': 'F', 'R': 'B', 'T': 'E'}
{'M': 'J', 'L': 'D', 'O': 'K', 'N': 'B', 'P': 'G', 'S': 'F', 'R': 'E', 'T': 'A'}
{'M': 'D', 'L': 'F', 'O': 'K', 'N': 'A', 'P': 'G', 'S': 'J', 'R': 'B', 'T': 'E'}
{'M': 'J', 'L': 'G', 'O': 'K', 'N': 'A', 'P': 'D', 'S': 'F', 'R': 'B', 'T': 'E'}
{'M': 'J', 'L': 'G', 'O': 'K', 'N': 'B', 'P': 'A', 'S': 'F', 'R': 'E', 'T': 'D'}
{'M': 'J', 'L': 'G', 'O': 'K', 'N': 'B', 'P': 'D', 'S': 'F', 'R': 'E', 'T': 'A'}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @ScottBoston different lists in which a specific element appears only in one couple

Comment: @Faber I've optimized my answer.  It now runs in only a few seconds for inputs of size 9 with minimal memory use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Optimized answer

(Insipred by [@Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53766273/2800876) but doesn't require Numpy):

```
from itertools import permutations
l1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
l2 = ["d", "e", "f"]
valid_pairings = [sorted(zip(i, l2)) for i in permutations(l1)]
```

valid_pairings is:

```
[
 [('a', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'f')],
 [('a', 'd'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'e')],
 [('a', 'e'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'f')],
 [('a', 'f'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'e')],
 [('a', 'e'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'd')],
 [('a', 'f'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'd')]
]
```

**Warning:** the size of the output is factiorial(n), where n is the size of one the smaller input.  At n = 14, this requires 100's of GBs of memory to store, more than most modern systems have.

---

## Old Answer

```
from itertools import product, combinations
def flatten(lst):
    return [item for sublist in lst for item in sublist]

l1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
l2 = ["d", "e", "f"]
all_pairings = combinations(product(l1, l2), min(len(l1), len(l2)))
# remove those pairings where an item appears more than once
valid_pairings = [i for i in all_pairings if len(set(flatten(i))) == len(flatten(i))]
```

Valid pairings is:

```
[
 (('a', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'f')),
 (('a', 'd'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'e')),
 (('a', 'e'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'f')),
 (('a', 'e'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'd')),
 (('a', 'f'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'e')),
 (('a', 'f'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'd'))
]
```

Comment: It works! but  it uses a lot of RAM, and with 8 elements already needs more than 16gb and I cannot run it!

Comment: @faber I've updated it to use less RAM.  Give it a try.  At the end of the day, the answer can be a fairly large data structure, so there's only so much room for optimization

Comment: @faber To be more specific, the number of rows in the output is factorial(n), where n is the size of one of the inputs.  For n = 8, this is only 40,320.  The bigger problem you will have here is the processing time to go through all_pairings, which is quite large.

Comment: I wouldnt call factorial growth "only". For n=70 there are more combinations than atoms in the known universe

Comment: @Jonas "Only 40,320" was a comment on a lower bound order of magnitude of memory that this would need to calculate the solution for n = 8 (10's of kBs is actually quite low).  I believe the relevant number here is n = 14, at which point this exceeds the amount of memory that most modern systems have (100's of GBs)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a brute force approach (don't use it for long lists), just sample the population enough times to be sure you have all possible combinations, make a set of it and sort the result.

```
from random import sample

x = ["a","b","c"]
y = ['d','e','f']

z = {tuple(sample(y,3)) for i in range(25)}

result = sorted([list(zip(x,z_)) for z_ in z])

>>>result
[[('a', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'f')],
 [('a', 'd'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'e')],
 [('a', 'e'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'f')],
 [('a', 'e'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'd')],
 [('a', 'f'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'e')],
 [('a', 'f'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'd')]]
```

This is not the way to go, it's just a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

Combine the "wives" with all permutations of the "husbands" and you get all combinations.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

husbands = ['d', 'e', 'f']
wifes = ['a', 'b', 'c']

permutations = list(itertools.permutations(husbands))
repetition = [wifes for _ in permutations]
res = np.dstack((repetition,permutations))
print(res)
```

Result is:

```
[[['a' 'd']
  ['b' 'e']
  ['c' 'f']]

 [['a' 'd']
  ['b' 'f']
  ['c' 'e']]

 [['a' 'e']
  ['b' 'd']
  ['c' 'f']]

 [['a' 'e']
  ['b' 'f']
  ['c' 'd']]

 [['a' 'f']
  ['b' 'd']
  ['c' 'e']]

 [['a' 'f']
  ['b' 'e']
  ['c' 'd']]]
```

If you prefer tuples:

```
res = res.view(dtype=np.dtype([('x', np.dtype('U1')), ('y', np.dtype('U1'))]))
res = res.reshape(res.shape[:-1])
print(res)
```

Result:

```
[[('a', 'd') ('b', 'e') ('c', 'f')]
 [('a', 'd') ('b', 'f') ('c', 'e')]
 [('a', 'e') ('b', 'd') ('c', 'f')]
 [('a', 'e') ('b', 'f') ('c', 'd')]
 [('a', 'f') ('b', 'd') ('c', 'e')]
 [('a', 'f') ('b', 'e') ('c', 'd')]]
```